# Jquery, Select Element, Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a pure newbie to JS and using several selects on a page. Each select element has two buttons "prev" and "next". Button of class "next" to go to next options and "prev" to previous option. On button click I detect which select should be used.

```
$("button").click(function () {
var btntyp= $(this).prop("class");
var usedSelector = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('select');
```

Now I'd like to use the class of clicked button to navigate through that specified element.
 I know this line of code takes me to next option

```
 usedSelector.children(':selected').next('option').prop('selected', true);
```

and this one to previous option:

```
usedSelector.children(':selected').prev('option').prop('selected', true);
```

But I want to keep my code short by using class of that button instead of writing a switch statement

How can I use button class of "next" or "prev" in

```
usedSelector.children(':selected')**USE BUTTON CLASS**.val();
```

or any other suggestions short way of using button's class to detect if go to prev or next option

Thanks very much

Comment: create snippet of scenario with enough code

Comment: Are you are looking for `usedSelector.children(':selected').siblings('.'+btntyp).val();`?

Comment: I'm trying to select prev/next option

Answer (score 0):

```
var className = usedSelector.children(':selected').attr('class');
```

should do the trick